# Load every 10mins generated web-application logs to mysql,automatically

Tags: mysql, linux, shell, awk

My purpose is to analyse web-application logs, use mysql as database. First, i filtered some useless information use awk to generate a filted-log, then i apply LOAD DATA import this log to mysql.

My problem is : those original logs generate every 10mins, every day. How can i  generate filted-logs once new web-application logs was generated? After new filted-logs generated, how can i import those files to mysql automatically?

the original logs:

```
20150414/0900.log 
20150414/0910.log
```

Comment: [maybe log directly to database](http://serverfault.com/questions/448140/syslog-ng-and-nginx-logs-to-mysql) ? (i know there's a dead link in there, but should be a start)

Comment: What is your question, exactly? It sounds like you need to import a bunch of text files in one go (automatically?). Please [edit] and remove all the information about logs.

Comment: Jan, Thanks for you advise! I just reorganized my question.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve tried to create a little script that will easy explain the way to do it. There you have an awk that controls all the readFiles. If the number of read files is bigger when a new read is done, the system will parse de name and save it in "readFiles" file which will be checked in the awk to assure the file was not read before.

Please, check your system will not erase old logs, and be careful of splitting readed control files, or creating new ones each day to avoid very big files.

```
//this will give you the today datae
date +%Y%m%d
```

This is the code:

```
echo "x" > readFiles

lastnum=0
num=0
count=0
while true
do
echo  "LOOKING FOR NEW FILES. LASTCOUNT="$lastcount
count=`ls ./2015*/*.log | wc -l`
echo $count
if [ $count -gt $lastnum ] 
then
lastnum=$count
`ls ./2015*/*.log | awk -F"/" 'BEGIN {
  while(( getline < "readFiles") > 0 ) {
    readedFiles[$0]
  }}
    {if(!($0 in readedFiles)){print $0}}
'`>> readFiles
echo "WAITING RESTART"
sleep 10
else
echo "NO NEW FILES FOUND"
sleep 10
fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing script to monitor logs. I use inotify-tools to trigger scripts on filesystem events, just few lines get things done.

```
NOW=$(date +"%Y%m%d")
while true ;
do
inotifywait -r -e create,move /rsynclog/logs/$NOW && \
/rsynclog/logs/generate.sh
done
```